# Where is the repository stored that is created for Google Dataform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform, google-dataform

I created a repository (without link to git) for Google Dataform and a workspace.

I initialized a first setup and pushed those first files.

Where can I see the repo and all the commits I do in there?
Looked in Cloud Storage, Artifact Registry, Cloud Source Repositories but can't find it.

[image: workspace google dataform]

Comment: Hi @Sander van den Oord, Dataform does not have all the functionality of Git  so without linking to Github you won’t be able to see the repository. I would suggest you create Dataform repositories (Git repositories containing Dataform code, essentially) and create code workspaces attached to those repositories. Edit code in those workspaces, push the results to the relevant Git repository.Let me know if that helps.

Comment: HI @Sander van den Oord, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

Dataform does not have all the functionality of Git so without linking to Github you won’t be able to see the repository. For your requirement, you can create Dataform repositories (Git repositories containing Dataform code, essentially) and create code workspaces attached to those repositories. Edit code in those workspaces, push the results to the relevant Git repository. You can also compile the repository/workspace Dataform code to Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs) of executable SQL and can also execute the compiled DAGs against BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The repositories are listed [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery/dataform), please see the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/create-repository#delete-repository) for more context.

You may also explore the possibility of connecting to a [remote repository](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/connect-repository), as the Dataform repository doesn't meet your requirement for viewing commits.

Comment: Hi Gourav:  my question is mainly about the commits, where can i see the different commits done in these repo's?

Comment: see my updated answer above.